# Static reference error for getDistanceTravelled() of transporter agent

Tags: anylogic, agent

I have an agent, called "AGV", which is used as a transporter in my model. It is the agent for my fleet named "OrderFleet".

How can I get the distance travelled at the end of my simulation runs for my AGVs?

If I put `AGV.getDistanceTravelled(METER);` into the "On destroy" of my main agent, called "main", I receive the error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
> getDistanceTravelled(Length Units) from the type AGV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AGV is an agent type not an agent, so you cannot use the `getDistanceTravelled()` function on it. To resolve your issue, start by creating a population of agents of type AGV by dragging and dropping to Main the "Agent" element of the "Agent" Palette.

[image]

[image]

Then, make sure the new transporters in your fleet block are added to that population by doing the following:
[image]

Now, in the On Destroy field you can write the following code:

```
for( AGV a : AGVs ) {
  traceln(a.getDistanceTravelled(METER));
}
```

This will return the distance travelled of each AGV in that fleet.

Comment: I've tried your solution with my Agents(AGV_Material), which I put into their later created population(PopulationAGVmaterials) by means of the TransporterFleet-block. Then I used for (AGV_Material a : PopulationAGVmaterials){traceln ...)} but Anylogic tells me that "PopulationAGVmaterials ist not a variable" -> but I thought this would make it iterate over an array, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code into the "on destroy" section of your AGV agent type, not Main. (Main is destroyed only once at the end of the model and does, obviously, not travel itself at all :) ).

If you do not have a separate agent type for the AGVs yet, you need to create (and apply) it. See the example models where this is shown in detail

Comment: Thank you! I am not really sure, what you mean with "agent type". I created an agent of type transporter with the wizard for it, but it is not in a population that lives on Main. I can access it through the projects-palette where all agents are listed.

Comment: Always create your own custom agent types and use populations, only this gives you full control over all your agents. By default, you get AGVs but cannot really do custom stuff with it beyond the standard things the blocks allow you to do. Study all the tutorials, many show how it is done

Comment: I still get the error with "static reference to non-static field". I guess the problem is that I do not access a single agent but the all agents. How can I access a single agent?